# Would the result of encrypting weak random data via AES-128 with a CSPRNG-generated key be considered strong/secure random data?

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generator

I am trying to understand the security implications of using a well known block (or stream but in this example block) cipher like AES-128 to produce pseudo-random data.

My specific question is **would the output of the following be considered cryptographically strong pseudo-random data**:

- Generate an AES-128 key using a CSPRNG.  (An IV would of course be securely generated as usual.)
- Seed an MT random number generator from a CSPRNG.
- Encrypt a stream of bytes from this MT source with AES-128 using the key above.  (Perhaps the MT source is unnecessary, encrypting zeros might do just as well?)
- Use the resulting bytes as pseudo-random data (for generating unique IDs that are "hard" to guess).
- Every so often reset the above and start over from new CSPRNG data.

The goal is to have something that is still cryptographically strong but faster to generate than using the system's CSPRNG.  <del>To answer the question ahead of time, yes I have timed it and /dev/urandom and other system CSPRNGs are significantly slower than the performance I'm looking for.</del> *(EDIT: I think I screwed up on my benchmarks, the Go standard library uses /dev/urandom and now I'm seeing it does give results in the 2-digit nanosecond range - very fast, so possibly I'm overkilling here.  The question remains valid though.)* Thus what I'm looking to understand is the security implications of doing the above.  Is there anything I'm missing about this idea or that I should be aware of in terms of potential pitfalls?  Is there a particular cipher mode that is well-suited to this use?  As far as I understand it, encrypting unknown input using a securely-generated key with a not-known-to-be-broken cipher like AES should result in cryptographically secure pseudo-random output.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: What you're describing sounds pretty close to a CTR_DRBG with AES.  Have you looked at that?
 https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf

Comment: This kind of question gets asked all the time. Block ciphers and hash functions don't care whether messages are random or non-random. Any non-repeating sequence is sufficient. Normally a counter is used. Anything more complicated is slower and has greater risk. (Implementation errors, side channels, bad seeds, and subtle ECB-like issues, for example.)